# Is it safe to create a user account using the id_token provided by google's sign in?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a chrome extension which allows users to exclusively login with google and no other provider.

In my (node + couchdb) backend I **need to construct a user account** from the auth Response provided by google's oauth2 api. I was thinking about using a hash of the **id_token** **as a password** after verifying the token using the [tokeninfo api](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo%20api.)

I realize that the id_token changes from time to time. In that case I was hoping to update the user's password automatically.

Here is the flow I had in mind:

1) User signs in on the front-end and gets an id_token from google
2) Id token is sent to the server and verified using the tokeninfo api
3) If verified, a user account is created with a password being the hash of the id_token.

Do you see any security holes with this flow? If so, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Maybe [security.se] is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably annoying to change user passwords all the time, and this ties your authentication too much to google. What if you want to implement password logins in the future, etc.

I would recommend to use something like proxy authentication instead.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html#api-auth-proxy

make sure to set

```
[couch_httpd_auth]
proxy_use_secret = true
```

in the config.

On a side note: if you sync the couchdb password with external secrets like in the question, you should sign the password with a hashed secret that you control completely.